# Duplicate code: Laravel migrations versus models

Tags: php, laravel-4

It seems to me that having duplicate createTable() methods in both a migration and a model is a bad/dangerous thing.  I would worry that someone will change the model and forget to change the corresponding migration (or vice versa), causing confusion and errors.

Does anyone know if it is possible (or wise) to simply call the createTable() method in the model from within the migration script?

If so, can someone point me to a working code sample so I can see how it is done?

Comment: Is it even necessary to have a createTable() method in the model???  That's how I've seen it done, but maybe that isn't right.  I don't see it anywhere in the Laravel documentation...

Comment: I've never seen createTable() in Laravel 4, especially in the model...I certainly wouldn't call database modification scripts in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to mark this as answered, per the comments above.  It appears that the createTable() method does not belong in the model.  I was fooled by a "more experienced" Laravel developer who did it that way.

:-/